# Ubuntu GNU GRUB settings

Tags: grub2

I'm not the kind of user with programming skills, so I don't know much about configuring grub with commands. My problem is that I have 8 or 9 starting options in grub menu, and I would like them to be just the 2, being my operating systems. I have windows 7 and ubuntu 12.4. How can I delete the rest of the options? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

At terminal copy and paste the following to install Grub Customizer :

Step I:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
```

Step II:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step III:

```
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Step IV:

```
grub-customizer
```

Unchecked items which you don't need save and restart your system.

Answer (score 1):

You can install grub-customizer. [Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664134) is the installation/user guide I found at Ubuntu forums. You can hide menu items by un-check the checkboxes.