# GRUB and making windows the default OS

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)

So I need to make my default OS Windows 7. I was told I would have to use grub but it's proving to be pretty difficult...how could I accomplish this task of changing my default OS?

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo su
cd /etc/grub.d/
mv 40_custom 08_custom
update-grub
```

this will pull Windows entry in the boot loader on top and will keep it that way even after updates

Answer (score 2):

From [all4naija](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121279/ubuntu-gnu-grub-settings)

At terminal copy and paste the following to install Grub Customizer :

Step I:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
```

Step II:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step III:

```
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Step IV:

```
grub-customizer
```

Unchecked items which you don't need save and restart your system.